In Magento 2.4.7, retrieving customer session data using the getCustomerData method is not Working
In Magento 2.4.7, the following code attempts to retrieve customer session data using the getCustomerData method, but it does not return any data
<?php
...
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Model\CustomerPriceProdcut;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as MainProduct;

class Product
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $customerPriceProdcut;
    public $scopeConfig;
    const ENABLE_PRICEPER_CUSTOMER = 'bliss/settings/enable';

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        CustomerPriceProdcut $customerPriceProdcut,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerPriceProdcut = $customerPriceProdcut;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Modify product price based on the customer's global price adjustment attribute or product-specific prices.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     * @param float $result
     * @return float
     */
    public function afterGetPrice($subject, $result)
    {
        $moduleEnableValue = $this->getModuleEnable();
        $customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();


I have identified the issue issue is  Full page caching when enabled at that customer session not working i have disabled then working can you provide best solution.

You can try this - https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-get-customer-data-from-session-when-cache-enabled/

From Magento version 2.4.7, the customer session does not work in certain areas such as the product page and category page. Instead of using the customer session method, you should set the customer id in httpContext when customer login(https://devhooks.in/blog/how-to-set-customer-data-in-httpcontext-and-retrieve-it-in-magento-2) and then retrieve it.
